# How to resolve the warning : DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations?

Tags: android, realm

When I run my app, which is also working, with Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 3, Gradle displays the following warning:
Note: C:\AndroidStudioProjects\simsim\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm\DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

This is my build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.8.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (app)

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
}
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sampietro.simsim"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 17
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
}
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
```

I would like to know what to do with this warning